# Migration issue from Junit 4 to Junit 5

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, junit5

I am migrating my codebase from junit4 to junit5.I have used mockito in my testcase.Below are the different  version that i am using for the dependency.

```
<junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
<junit.platform.version>1.2.0</junit.platform.version>
<org.mockito.version>1.10.19</org.mockito.version>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I have used the annotation `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to run my mockito code.Replaced the same with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`

But when i run the test case i get the below error. Any suggestion to solve this issue. I suspect is there any dependency version issue which is causing this problem.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/quality/Strictness
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at..
```

Thanks
-Sam

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JUnit5 `MockitoExtension` uses `org.mockito.quality.Strictness` so in order to use `MockitoExtension` you'll need to use a version of `mockito-core` which contains `org.mockito.quality.Strictness`. `mockito-core:1.10.19` does not contain that class because that class was added in Mockito 2.x. So, in order to use `MockitoExtension` you'll need to use at least version 2.x of `mockito-core`.

The Mockito docs don't make this explicit but I suspect the expectation is that you'll use the same Mockito version for `mockito-core` and for `mockito-junit-jupiter`.

The following dependencies will allow you to use the JUnit5 `MockitoExtension` successfully:

```
<org.mockito.version>2.19.0</org.mockito.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mockito.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @glytching.It helped me to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use same version for mockito-junit-jupiter and mockito-core, but fails.

At last I init the mocks myself in `@BeforeEach` block.

```
@BeforeEach
private void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response @glytching .With your input i was able to find the correct version dependency for me and it resolved my issue. Below is the version that i used to resolve the same.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Also i needed **mockito-core => version 2.22.0**. But above mentioned **mockito-junit-jupiter** comes with mockito core dependency internally.So no need to add that dependency.

Comment: Are you sure?  I tried with these versions and for me it didn't work. I had to add the dependency specified in @glytching's answer.